# Javascript to coffeescript error 3

Tags: coffeescript

```
const supportOnInput = 'oninput' in document.createElement('input');
$('textarea[maxlength]').each(function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  const maxLength = parseInt($this.attr('maxlength'));

  const el = $('<span class="character-count">' + (maxLength-$this.val().length) + '</span>');
  el.insertAfter($this);

  $this.bind(supportOnInput ? 'input' : 'keyup', function(){
    const cc = $this.val().length;

  el.text(maxLength - cc);

  if (maxLength - 10 < cc) {
    el.css('color', 'red');
  } else {
    el.css('color', null);
  }
  });
});
```

converted to coffeescript as below

```
supportOnInput = 'oninput' of document.createElement('input')
$('textarea[maxlength]').each ->
  $this = $(this)
  maxLength = parseInt($this.attr('maxlength'))
  el = $('<span class="character-count">' + maxLength - ($this.val().length) + '</span>')
  el.insertAfter $this
  $this.bind if supportOnInput then 'input' else 'keyup', ->
    cc = $this.val().length
    el.text maxLength - cc
    if maxLength - 10 < cc
      el.css 'color', 'red'
    else
      el.css 'color', null
    return
  return

# ---
# generated by js2coffee 2.2.0
```

and get error at   `$this.bind if supportOnInput then 'input' else 'keyup', ->`

can anybody please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the coffeescript to Javascript conversion has a bug. Coffeescript doesn't have a ternary operator, instead if uses `if ... then ... else ...`.

But Coffeescript also has a postfix form of `doSomething() if ...`

I think the compiler cannot distinguish between the regular and postfix forms. You could probably fix it with parenthesis, but a more readable solution is to split it into two lines.

Change the offending line:

```
 $this.bind if supportOnInput then 'input' else 'keyup', ->
```

To:

```
 eventType = if supportOnInput then 'input' else 'keyup'  
 $this.bind eventType, ->
```